# Can I extract TFS Service hook trigger message in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, service, tfs, hook, webhooks

I am trying to trigger jenkins via TFS service hook, I want to use jenkin to extract out check in information to create a log using powershell script. I have it set up to trigger the jenkins on check in. but I can not figure out a way to parse message info sent from TFS service hook. Looking at https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md I can see there are few environment variables created on trigger but I want to extract some of the check in information as in username who checked in and tfs id it was checked in against etc. TFS_USERNAME only record the username of the account that is configured to access tfs in Jekins

Comment: What do you mean about "tfs id"?

Comment: the User Story/ Bug number of the tfs item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TFS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-ca/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets) to get a changset on Jekins side. The API is as below:

```
GET http://({server:port})/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets/{id}?api-version=1.0
```

Comment: That will be set up in Jenkins right? Can I not use TFS hook request message body in Jenkins? It already has the information I need.

Comment: TFS provides REST API, you can get TFS related information from API. Check-in information only exists in TFS.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to extract the hooks that Jenkins received in the build trigger. However, if the Jenkins job download the latest source code to local after the job is triggered, the information you want like the user who check in the changes is already in local. You can simple run `tf changeset /latest /noprompt` to get this information. And you can also install [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) and then create a powershell script to get these information via [TFS Powershell Command](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/21/powershell-and-tfs-the-basics-and-beyond/). For example:

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
$cs = Get-TfsChangeset -Latest
Write-Host $cs.CommitterDisplayName
Write-Host $cs.Committer
```